# How does protobuf helps or make it easier to do schema validation of message stream?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

I have a Kafka topic that would contains different kinds of message that is different kinds of stuctures.
The messages of json kind. There is a need to evaluate the schema of every message/record.
I would  like to know how we can leverage protobuf here to make things easier. where exactly should I insert protobuf.
Also a message of protobuf encapsulated means that it is always schema safe?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [Avro would make more sense than Protobuf, in terms of Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/avro-kafka-data/). *However*, the new version of the Confluent Schema Registry does support Protobuf now, so... moving on...

> where exactly should I insert protobuf.

Your messages are already JSON, so you wouldn't really "insert" anything...

If you want to use Protobuf, you would no longer be using JSON. You would have to **rewrite** both your Producer and Consumer code to not use `String(De)serializer` or `JSON(De)Serializer` and rather [find some `ProtobufSerializer`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/5.5.x/protobuf-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/protobuf/KafkaProtobufSerializer.java) that you would use instead.

The schemas must then be exist on both "sides" of the Kafka topic, in each application's code (or you'd fetch them from a remote Registry). And they are used to validate and (de)serialize the messages that are sent/received.

> Also a message of protobuf encapsulated means that it is always schema safe?

Not necessarily, but I don't know enough about Protobuf to really say.